# Facebook graph api returns "Unsupported get request" when I try to get a post data created by my app using the post user access token

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application that posts on behalf of the users (approved by Facebook), According to the graph API documentation I should be able to call

```
/{post_id}?access_token={PostUserAccess_token}
```

In [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post), in *Permissions* paragraph, there is written:

> A user access token can read any post your application created on behalf of that user.

I'm using the same post id (ex: XXXX_YYYYY) returned after the post, and the user access token to make the call but I get this error:

```
"message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at ....",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
```

Any idea what are the possibilities of this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me. This GET request was working a few days ago. I think the problem is with the Graph API.
Whats funny is that you can make POST request with the same parameters (you have to add something to change like message='TEST') and it will allow you to edit the post if you access token is working.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: so they only way is to contact Facebook support?